# Python Telebot Функция спотыкается об юзеров заблокировавших бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

День добрый, есть Телеграмм бот в котором реализована команда отправки уведомления об обновлении всем юзерам:

```py
if e.demojize(m.text) == "Уведомление об обновлении":
            db = sqlite3.connect(DBCONNECT)
            db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
            c = db.execute(f"SELECT * FROM userss where username <> '@None'")
            log = c.fetchall()
            c.close()
            db.close()
            BotChecking = TeleBot(BOTAPIKEY)
            countSended = 0

            for i in log:
                countSended += 1
                BotChecking.send_message(i['tgid'], texts_for_bot["alert_to_update"], parse_mode="HTML")

            BotChecking.send_message(CONFIG['admin_tg_id'],
                                        f"Сообщение отправлено {countSended} пользователям", parse_mode="HTML")
```

И всё работает замечательно, если кто нибудь из юзеров не заблочит бота. В таком случае бот споткнется об него и прекратит отправлять сообщения, а в консоль выкинет это:

```
(async_telebot.py:543 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 403. Description: Forbidden: bot was blocked by the user"
```

Как мне пропускать таких юзеров и продолжать перебор массива и отправку сообщений?

Comment: Я не понял, это исключение или просто уведомление кода о том, что он не работает?

Comment: Это ошибка которая обрывает перебор массива

Comment: А процесс, в котором работает программа, завершает свою работу при этом?

Comment: Если да, попробуйте перехватить через try-except. Если нет, то, наверняка в документации можно найти, как проверить, заблокировал ли юзер бота и делать проверку перед действием

Comment: сейчас попробую.
заранее спасибо

Comment: а на счет процесса (хоть уже и не актуально), бот запущен как сервис, по этому в случае ошибок перезапускается сразу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как подсказал [Юрыч bro](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/482957/%D0%AE%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%87-bro)(за что ему огромное спасибо), нужно было использовать конструкцию `try: except:`

Итоговый код выглядит так:

```
if e.demojize(m.text) == "Уведомление об обновлении":
    db = sqlite3.connect(DBCONNECT)
    db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    c = db.execute(f"SELECT * FROM userss where username <> '@None'")
    log = c.fetchall()
    c.close()
    db.close()
    BotChecking = TeleBot(BOTAPIKEY)
    countSended = 0
    countBlocked = 0

    for i in log:
        try: 
            countSended += 1
            BotChecking.send_message(i['tgid'], texts_for_bot["alert_to_update"], reply_markup=Butt_main, parse_mode="HTML")
        except:
            countSended -= 1
            countBlocked += 1
            pass
    BotChecking.send_message(CONFIG['admin_tg_id'], f"Сообщение отправлено {countSended} пользователям. {countBlocked} пользователей заблокировало бота", parse_mode="HTML")
```

Comment: pass в блоке except лишнее. Оно нужно только в случае, когда нужна заглушка, чтобы блок ничего не делал.

Comment: Спасибо) мне просто Codeium в VS Code подсказал так, я и оставил)

Comment: попробуйте вместо codeium cody ai. Мне лично очень помогает

Comment: Окей, спасибо, гляну